# iPhone 4.0 API to invoke the phone lock screen?

Tags: iphone

Is there an API with the latest 4.0 SDK or earlier that allows an app to programatically invoke the iPhone's lock screen (the one that says "Slide to Unlock") ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do anything from the app that interferes with the users ability to control the phone. You could lock someone out of their phone with that capability.